# Getting an error when using the gtfarser module on windows

Tags: module, bioinformatics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYYcl.png)

As shown in the image, I am getting an error that I am not understanding how to resolve, can someone please help me resolve this issue please?

Thank you!

I tried looking up similar cases but to no avail